# Brew installed Scala and Play with Akka throwing an exception

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, akka

I'm getting a really awful error with my application.

I suspect it may be because the default play version, the default akka version and the default scala version are in conflict.  There seem to be two or three competing forces at work here.  Firstly, I am using the sbt-idea plugin, which does not work with play 2.0.3.  This means I am using Play 2.0.1.  Secondly, neither play 2.0.3 nor 2.0.1 have a scala 2.9.2 version, even though these are the versions installed from brew, which is the recommended mechanism.  I hope I'm wrong or am missing something here that is fixable.  When attempting to use actors, the following stack trace occurs:

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[MatchError:   ModuleSym(SymbolInfo(nameRef=34, ownerRef=9, flags=0x120, infoRef=35)) (of class org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.UnPickler$$anonfun$read$3$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$13)]]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311) [akka-actor-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619) [akka-actor-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196) [akka-actor-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
Caused by: scala.MatchError: ModuleSym(SymbolInfo(nameRef=34, ownerRef=9, flags=0x120, infoRef=35)) (of class org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.UnPickler$$anonfun$read$3$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$13)
at org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.ClassDeclExtractor.parsePath(ClassDeclExtractor.scala:287) ~[scalabeans-0.2.jar:na]
at org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.ClassDeclExtractor$$anonfun$13$$anon$13.<init>(ClassDeclExtractor.scala:277) ~[scalabeans-0.2.jar:na]
at org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.ClassDeclExtractor$$anonfun$13.apply(ClassDeclExtractor.scala:276) ~[scalabeans-0.2.jar:na]
at org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.ClassDeclExtractor$$anonfun$13.apply(ClassDeclExtractor.scala:258) ~[scalabeans-0.2.jar:na]
at org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig.Memoizable$$anon$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Memoizable.scala:24) ~[scalabeans-0.2.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:188) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3-2]
```

Comment: Is the 'org.scalastuff.scalabeans.sig' your package? Or not? If so, you got a pattern match error in you code. This happens if there no match / default in a pattern matching clause.

Comment: no, this isn't my code, I'm guessing it's related to the piece that deserializes JSON into Scala objects.